# Inheritance in JS: this.base = Class(); this.base() or ...?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to "get" inheritance in JS.
I just discovered a neat way to basically copy all properties from one object into another:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name="Mr or Miss: "+name;

  this.introduce = function(){
    console.log("Hi, I am "+this.name);
  }
}

function Employee(name,title){
  this.title=title;

  this.base=Person;
  this.base(name);  

}

e = new Employee('tony', 'manager')
e.introduce();
```

Note that I have a Person() class with a constructor, and its attribute "name" is generated by the constructor.
The great thing about this is also that then employee has ALSO the name in the constructor -- and voila', it creates the Person object using the same parameter.

If I had done this with the "Prototype" way:

```
function Person(name){

  this.introduce = function(){
    console.log("Hi, I am "+this.name);
  }
}

function Employee(name, title){
  this.name = name; /*  ?!?!?!?!? I can't call the proper constructor here */
  this.title = title;
}
Employee.prototype= new Person(); /* ?!?!? NO NAME HERE..>? */
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;


e = new Employee('tony', 'manager')
e.introduce();
```

Err.... now what? I can't even complete this: this.name in Employee cannot be set using the proper Person constructor; the creation of a Person object happens only once in the inheritance.

So... what am I missing? Is the first example I gave "the" way to go in my case? And is there a way to have the same result with the second example?

Help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This kind of prototype inheritance is often done this way:

```
function Parent() {}

function Child() {
    Parent.call(this); // call the constructor of the parent
}

var Constr = function() {};
Constr.prototype = Parent.prototype;

Child.prototype = new Constr();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

So the "trick" is to assign the `Parent.prototype` as prototype to an empty function and set a new instance of this function as prototype of `Child`.

This is done so that extending `Child.prototype` does not extend `Parent.prototype`.

You also have to call the parent's constructor in the child's constructor. I guess this is the part you struggled with. Every function has a [`call` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method which let's you explicitly set the element `this` should refer to inside the function.

In your example, it would look like:

```
function Employee(name,title){
  this.title=title;

  Person.call(this, name);
}
```

without assigning the constructor to a property of the instance.

In your example, `this.base(name)` works, because through assigning the constructor to a property of the instance (and calling it this way), `this` inside the function refers to that instance.

---

There are several libraries implementing this pattern, e.g. [Google Closure library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html):

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /** @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

Comment: I totally understand the function in the Google Closure library (wow, I must be getting somewhere :D ) But! From what I understand, when I create derived class, it's up to me if I want to inherit the internal attributes or not, typing  Parent.call(this); or  Parent.call(this, name) -- is that right? Wouldn't you ALWAYS want to do that though, really?

Comment: @Tony: I think you would. But if you have classical inheritance in mind (like Java), then you also have to call the parent's constructor if you overwrite it. The only difference is that in JavaScript you basically *always* overwrite the constructor because this is how we simulate classes. So it is actually not that different and maybe it is even easier to understand what is going on.